# Azure Java SDK - Create multiple VMs using image simultaneously

Tags: java, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to create several VM's in azure using the Java SDK.
The thing is that after the machines are created, I'm unable to connect (the public ip is added manually after the java code creates the VM's- this is not mandatory for me, public ip is not a requirement).

This is the code that I'm using ti create the machines.

```
List<Creatable<VirtualMachine>> creatableVirtualMachines = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Creatable<NetworkInterface>> creatableNetworkInterfaces = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Creatable<Disk>> creatableDisk = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < vmCount; i++) {

        Creatable<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaceCreatable = azure.networkInterfaces()
                .define("testNIC-" + i)
                .withRegion(Region.EUROPE_WEST)
                .withExistingResourceGroup("TestRes2")
                .withExistingPrimaryNetwork(network)
                .withSubnet("default")
                .withPrimaryPrivateIPAddressDynamic();
        creatableNetworkInterfaces.add(networkInterfaceCreatable);

        Creatable<Disk> disksCreatable= azure.disks()
                .define(SdkContext.randomResourceName("test_dsk", 30))
                .withRegion(Region.EUROPE_WEST)
                .withNewResourceGroup("TestRes2")
                .withWindowsFromVhd("image url")
                .withSizeInGB(127)
                .withSku(DiskSkuTypes.STANDARD_LRS);
        creatableDisk.add(disksCreatable);
    }

    networkInterfaces = azure.networkInterfaces().create(creatableNetworkInterfaces);
    networkInterfacesKeys = new ArrayList(networkInterfaces.keySet());
    disks = azure.disks().create(creatableDisk);
    disksKeys = new ArrayList(disks.keySet());

    for (int i = 0; i < vmCount; i++) {
        // Create one virtual machine Creatable
        Creatable<VirtualMachine> virtualMachineCreatable = azure.virtualMachines()
                .define("TESTVM-" + i)
                .withRegion(Region.EUROPE_WEST)
                .withExistingResourceGroup("TestRes2")
                .withExistingPrimaryNetworkInterface(networkInterfaces.get(networkInterfacesKeys.get(i)))
                .withSpecializedOSDisk(disks.get(disksKeys.get(i)), OperatingSystemTypes.WINDOWS)
                .withSize(VirtualMachineSizeTypes.STANDARD_B2S);
        // add the virtual machine Creatable to the list
        creatableVirtualMachines.add(virtualMachineCreatable);
    }
    virtualMachines = azure.virtualMachines().create(creatableVirtualMachines);
    virtualMachinesKeys = new ArrayList(virtualMachines.keySet());
```

**EDIT:**

When I'm not using an image but rather a "LatestImage"

```
.withLatestWindowsImage("MicrosoftWindowsServer", "WindowsServer", "2012-R2-Datacenter")
```

it works.

Comment: What about your image file when you create the OS disk? You should install the Azure agent in it. So you can connect it.

Comment: Seemed like the issue was the fact that I didn't use Storage account.

Comment: Really? If you create the managed VM then it does not need the storage account. Do you?